# How to refresh home page with only once log in?? jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I want to perform load testing on my site using j-meter. My scenario is
1. Log in with user
2. Home page opens.
3. Refresh home page 100 times.
When i execute test case it log in and open home page every time. but i want to refresh only home page with one time log in. can you please guide me how can i execute my test case??

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a HTTP sampler for the login, and another to refresh the homepage.

I think that a good way to do this would be with a Loop Controller, that will loop the "refresh homepage" HTTP sampler 100 times. See the very simple example test plan below, this will execute LOGIN TO HOMEPAGE once and LOAD HOMEPAGE 100 times:

[image: Simple Loop Controller]